# Change Image Button in cell of table view

Tags: swift, uitableview, button, cell

I have two classes `TableViewController` and `CustomCell` then connect the button(`likeBtn`) in `IB` to `CustomCell`.

And now, I wanna to change the image of this button!

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        // Configure the cell...            
        cell.likeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableViewController.liked), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

@objc func liked(sender: UIButton) {

        cell.likeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked.png"), for: .normal)
        cell.likeBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
```

But in the `liked()`, I've errors about `cell.likeBtn`.

I'm programming with **swift 4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way should be:

```
@objc func liked(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked.png"), for: .normal)
    sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I thought  about `sender.tag` or pass parameter, lol. And now I encounter to a **BUG** that is about when clicked on first cell, some cells is clicked in table!!

Comment: If you only want certain cell button to be clicked, just do this in cellForRowAt: if indexPath.row == (which row) {cell.likeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableViewController.liked), for: .touchUpInside)}

Comment: thx, but I want click on any cell in the table and saves this for only I clicked!

Comment: you can always add tag, your tag can be indexPath.row so that every button has a unique tag